# How to make Bootstrap buttons inactive dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a webpage that uses jquery to show and hide content depending on the user selection.

The site contains three main  containers: one for a search, one for the results of the search, and another for the visualization of the results of the search.

I'm using buttons to switch from one 'page' to another. The problem is that the results and visualization buttons are active even before a search is done, which is not correct. I want to adapt my code so the only way the button with results works is when there is a search done. The same would be true for the visualization button. How can I do this?

I would appreciate any help!

Thanks!

Comment: There's a better way to do what you're doing. I promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable it :

```
$('button').prop('disabled', true);
```

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/48HKD/